# What is a good way to match strings against patterns and extract values?

Tags: string, rust, pattern-matching

I am trying get something like this (doesn't work):

```
match input {
    "next" => current_question_number += 1,
    "prev" => current_question_number -= 1,
    "goto {x}" => current_question_number = x,
    // ...
    _ => status = "Unknown Command".to_owned()
}
```

I tried two different versions of `Regex`:

```
go_match = regex::Regex::new(r"goto (\d+)?").unwrap();
// ...
match input {
    ...
    x if go_match.is_match(x) => current_question_number = go_match.captures(x).unwrap().get(1).unwrap().as_str().parse().unwrap(),
    _ => status = "Unknown Command".to_owned()
}
```

and

```
let cmd_match = regex::Regex::new(r"([a-zA-Z]+) (\d+)?").unwrap();
// ...
if let Some(captures) = cmd_match.captures(input.as_ref()) {
        let cmd = captures.get(1).unwrap().as_str().to_lowercase();
        if let Some(param) = captures.get(2) {
            let param = param.as_str().parse().unwrap();
            match cmd.as_ref() {
                "goto" => current_question_number = param,
            }
        } else {
            match cmd.as_ref() {
                "next" => current_question_number += 1,
                "prev" => current_question_number -= 1,
            }
        }
    } else {
        status = "Unknown Command".to_owned();
    }
```

Both seem like a ridiculously long and and complicated way to do something pretty common, am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a master `Regex` that captures all the interesting components then build a `Vec` of all the captured pieces. This `Vec` can then be matched against:

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let input = "goto 4";
    let mut current_question_number = 0;

    // Create a regex that matches on the union of all commands
    // Each command and argument is captured
    // Using the "extended mode" flag to write a nicer Regex
    let input_re = Regex::new(
        r#"(?x)
        (next) |
        (prev) |
        (goto)\s+(\d+)
        "#
    ).unwrap();

    // Execute the Regex
    let captures = input_re.captures(input).map(|captures| {
        captures
            .iter() // All the captured groups
            .skip(1) // Skipping the complete match
            .flat_map(|c| c) // Ignoring all empty optional matches
            .map(|c| c.as_str()) // Grab the original strings
            .collect::<Vec<_>>() // Create a vector
    });

    // Match against the captured values as a slice
    match captures.as_ref().map(|c| c.as_slice()) {
        Some(["next"]) => current_question_number += 1,
        Some(["prev"]) => current_question_number -= 1,
        Some(["goto", x]) => {
            let x = x.parse().expect("can't parse number");
            current_question_number = x;
        }
        _ => panic!("Unknown Command: {}", input),
    }

    println!("Now at question {}", current_question_number);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You have a mini language for picking questions:

- pick the *next* question
- pick the *prev* question
- *goto* a specific question

If your requirements end here a `Regex` based solution fits perfectly.

If your DSL may evolve a parser based solution is worth considering.

The parser combinator [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) is a powerful tool to build a grammar starting from basic elements.

Your language has these characteristics:

- it has three alternatives statements (`alt!`): *next*, *prev*, *goto \d+*
- the most complex statement "goto {number}" is composed of the keyword (`tag!`) *goto* in front of (`preceded!`) a *number* (`digit!`).
- any numbers of whitespaces (`ws!`) has to be ignored

These requirements translate in this implementation:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use nom::{IResult, digit};
use nom::types::CompleteStr;

// we have for now two types of outcome: absolute or relative cursor move
pub enum QMove {
    Abs(i32),
    Rel(i32)
}

pub fn question_picker(input: CompleteStr) -> IResult<CompleteStr, QMove> {
    ws!(input,
        alt!(
            map!(
                tag!("next"),
                |_| QMove::Rel(1)
            ) |
            map!(
                tag!("prev"),
                |_| QMove::Rel(-1)
            ) |
            preceded!(
                tag!("goto"),
                map!(
                    digit,
                    |s| QMove::Abs(std::str::FromStr::from_str(s.0).unwrap())
                )
            )
        )
    )
}

fn main() {
    let mut current_question_number = 60;
    let first_line = "goto 5";

    let outcome = question_picker(CompleteStr(first_line));

    match outcome {
        Ok((_, QMove::Abs(n))) => current_question_number = n,
        Ok((_, QMove::Rel(n))) => current_question_number += n,
        Err(err) => {panic!("error: {:?}", err)}
    }

    println!("Now at question {}", current_question_number);
}
```

Comment: The regex answer worked for me, but this does look very interesting (never came across nom before).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str::split` for this ([playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=61257fd07c6c8455138ce86b3c27d276&version=stable&mode=debug))

```
fn run(input: &str) {
    let mut toks = input.split(' ').fuse();
    let first = toks.next();
    let second = toks.next();

    match first {
        Some("next") => println!("next found"),
        Some("prev") => println!("prev found"),
        Some("goto") => match second {
            Some(num) => println!("found goto with number {}", num),
            _ => println!("goto with no parameter"),
        },
        _ => println!("invalid input {:?}", input),
    }
}

fn main() {
    run("next");
    run("prev");
    run("goto 10");
    run("this is not valid");
    run("goto"); // also not valid but for a different reason
}
```

will output

```
next found
prev found
found goto with number 10
invalid input "this is not valid"
goto with no parameter
```

Comment: You would need to add another layer to check if the second parameter is a number or not, which I guess is alright, but I'll still need to have a lot of repeated code if I want to have multiple commands like `cmd num`, this gets even worse if I need more parameters.

Comment: You should probably call `fuse` on `toks`: [*calling `next()` again may or may not eventually start returning `Some(Item)` again at some point*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next).

Comment: @Shepmaster totally agree, I added fuse. I will definitely be using this more in the future, thanks for pointing this out